# error al instalar ionic

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic-framework

Tengo un problema en la instalacion de la librería de ionic: 
escribo en la terminal...
`npm install -g cordova ionic`
y la terminal me devuelve:

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead

/usr/local/lib
└─┬ ionic@3.6.0 
  ├─┬ @ionic/cli-utils@1.6.0 
  │ ├─┬ archiver@1.3.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ archiver-utils@1.3.0 
  │ │ │ ├── lazystream@1.0.0 
  │ │ │ └─┬ normalize-path@2.1.1 
  │ │ │   └── remove-trailing-separator@1.0.2 
  │ │ ├── async@2.5.0 
  │ │ ├── buffer-crc32@0.2.13 
  │ │ ├─┬ readable-stream@2.3.3 
  │ │ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
  │ │ │ ├── isarray@1.0.0 
  │ │ │ ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
  │ │ │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.1 
  │ │ │ ├── string_decoder@1.0.3 
  │ │ │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ tar-stream@1.5.4 
  │ │ │ ├── bl@1.2.1 
  │ │ │ ├── end-of-stream@1.4.0 
  │ │ │ └── xtend@4.0.1 
  │ │ ├── walkdir@0.0.11 
  │ │ └─┬ zip-stream@1.2.0 
  │ │   └─┬ compress-commons@1.2.0 
  │ │     └─┬ crc32-stream@2.0.0 
  │ │       └── crc@3.4.4 
  │ ├── ci-info@1.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ cross-spawn@4.0.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ lru-cache@4.1.1 
  │ │ │ ├── pseudomap@1.0.2 
  │ │ │ └── yallist@2.1.2 
  │ │ └─┬ which@1.2.14 
  │ │   └── isexe@2.0.0 
  │ ├── dargs@5.1.0 
  │ ├── dev-null@0.1.1 
  │ ├─┬ inquirer@3.2.1 
  │ │ ├── ansi-escapes@2.0.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ cli-cursor@2.1.0 
  │ │ │ └─┬ restore-cursor@2.0.0 
  │ │ │   ├─┬ onetime@2.0.1 
  │ │ │   │ └── mimic-fn@1.1.0 
  │ │ │   └── signal-exit@3.0.2 
  │ │ ├── cli-width@2.1.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ external-editor@2.0.4 
  │ │ │ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.18 
  │ │ │ ├── jschardet@1.5.0 
  │ │ │ └─┬ tmp@0.0.31 
  │ │ │   └── os-tmpdir@1.0.2 
  │ │ ├── figures@2.0.0 
  │ │ ├── mute-stream@0.0.7 
  │ │ ├─┬ run-async@2.3.0 
  │ │ │ └── is-promise@2.1.0 
  │ │ ├── rx-lite@4.0.8 
  │ │ ├── rx-lite-aggregates@4.0.8 
  │ │ └── through@2.3.8 
  │ ├─┬ leek@0.0.24 
  │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.6.8 
  │ │ │ └── ms@2.0.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ lodash.assign@3.2.0 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ lodash._baseassign@3.2.0 
  │ │ │ │ └── lodash._basecopy@3.0.1 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ lodash._createassigner@3.1.1 
  │ │ │ │ ├── lodash._bindcallback@3.0.1 
  │ │ │ │ ├── lodash._isiterateecall@3.0.9 
  │ │ │ │ └── lodash.restparam@3.6.1 
  │ │ │ └─┬ lodash.keys@3.1.2 
  │ │ │   ├── lodash._getnative@3.9.1 
  │ │ │   ├── lodash.isarguments@3.1.0 
  │ │ │   └── lodash.isarray@3.0.4 
  │ │ └── rsvp@3.6.2 
  │ ├── lodash@4.17.4 
  │ ├── ncp@2.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ slice-ansi@1.0.0 
  │ │ └── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 
  │ ├── string-width@2.1.1 
  │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
  │ │ └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ superagent@3.5.2 
  │ │ ├── component-emitter@1.2.1 
  │ │ ├── cookiejar@2.1.1 
  │ │ ├── extend@3.0.1 
  │ │ ├─┬ form-data@2.2.0 
  │ │ │ ├── asynckit@0.4.0 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.5 
  │ │ │ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0 
  │ │ │ └─┬ mime-types@2.1.16 
  │ │ │   └── mime-db@1.29.0 
  │ │ ├── formidable@1.1.1 
  │ │ ├── methods@1.1.2 
  │ │ ├── mime@1.3.6 
  │ │ └── qs@6.5.0 
  │ ├── uuid@3.1.0 
  │ └─┬ wrap-ansi@2.1.0 
  │   ├─┬ string-width@1.0.2 
  │   │ ├── code-point-at@1.1.0 
  │   │ └─┬ is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 
  │   │   └── number-is-nan@1.0.1 
  │   └─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.1 
  │     └── ansi-regex@2.1.1 
  ├─┬ chalk@2.0.1 
  │ ├─┬ ansi-styles@3.2.0 
  │ │ └─┬ color-convert@1.9.0 
  │ │   └── color-name@1.1.3 
  │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 
  │ └─┬ supports-color@4.2.1 
  │   └── has-flag@2.0.0 
  ├── diff@3.3.0 
  ├── minimist@1.2.0 
  ├─┬ opn@4.0.2 
  │ ├── object-assign@4.1.1 
  │ └─┬ pinkie-promise@2.0.1 
  │   └── pinkie@2.0.4 
  ├─┬ os-name@2.0.1 
  │ ├── macos-release@1.1.0 
  │ └── win-release@1.1.1 
  ├─┬ rimraf@2.6.1 
  │ └─┬ glob@7.1.2 
  │   ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0 
  │   ├─┬ inflight@1.0.6 
  │   │ └── wrappy@1.0.2 
  │   ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.4 
  │   │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.8 
  │   │   ├── balanced-match@1.0.0 
  │   │   └── concat-map@0.0.1 
  │   ├── once@1.4.0 
  │   └── path-is-absolute@1.0.1 
  ├── semver@5.4.1 
  ├── ssh-config@1.0.1 
  ├─┬ tar@2.2.1 
  │ ├── block-stream@0.0.9 
  │ ├─┬ fstream@1.0.11 
  │ │ ├── graceful-fs@4.1.11 
  │ │ └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
  │ │   └── minimist@0.0.8 
  │ └── inherits@2.0.3 
  └── tslib@1.7.1 

npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova' -> '/usr/local/bin/cordova'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova' -> '/usr/local/bin/cordova'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/cordova' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/ivan/npm-debug.log
```

¿qué podría hacer al respecto?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo estas me pareció que estas en  `linux` Por que 'Mac' es similar, lo que te recomiendo es que ejecutes esa linea en `root`(linux) o en Mac (como administrador), solo puedo ayudar a quienes están en linux y es anteponiendo el comando  `sudo` a dicha linea  en `Ubuntu`.

En caso de estar en un `Debian`, me temo si mal no recuerdo instalar el `sudo`, y fijarte que tu usuario este entre los usuarios con acceso a root "sudoers"

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
```

por favor, quien tiene la solución al problema del  en Mac comparta.

Comment: estoy en Mac, al escribir en el terminal sudo npm install -g cordova ionic me devuelve los mismo.

Comment: es error de permisos , no tienes permisos,de Mac no conozco. pero por el mensaje es una cuestión de permisos.fijate como ejecutar como administrador en Mac, fijate en el siguiente comentario que te hago:

Comment: npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova' -> '/usr/local/bin/cordova'        **después te dice:**           npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/ivan/npm-debug.log

Comment: vale ya mi mac es capaz de instalar app de cualquier sitio, pero introduzco de nuevo: sudo npm install -g cordova ionic.   y me aparece lo siguiente....

Comment: npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
/usr/local/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
/usr/local/bin/ionic -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
/usr/local/lib
├── cordova@7.0.1 
└── ionic@3.6.0

Comment: algo mas corto que representa menor problema pero sigue estando ahí

Comment: fijate si funciona.por que a mi en linux . instalando módulos me da ese npm WARN , es un warning, capas te funciona, pero lo peor que te puede pasar es que no te funcione el modulo en algunas versiones de android, o el SO en cuestión

Comment: Proba crear un proyecto, y comentame, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El `WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead` es porque ionic esta usando una version algo obsoleta de un paquete y el mismo cambio de nombre de `node-uuid` a `uuid` en una actualización posterior, ahora bien leyendo el isue que reportar este problema [#155](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid/issues/155) es solo una advertencia cuando actualice cordoba el paquete se actualizara.

El verdadero problema que tienes es un problema de permisos para instalar los paquetes ya que la `-g` hace referencia a `--global` por lo que deberías intentar instalar usando el usuario sudoers para no tener problemas.

Saludos

Comment: estoy en mac, al escribir en el terminal sudo npm install -g cordova ionic me devuelve los mismo.